# JavaScript split words, keep position

Tags: javascript, python, split

I have a text file for example:

```
<1.0>The man went up the hill.
<1.1>The woman sat on the bench.
```

Is there a way to split each word and keep it's position.  So it will output:

```
<1.0>The
<1.0>man
...
<1.1>The
<1.1>woman
```

I have seen many examples of `str.split(" ");`, but have not come across a way to keep the first word of every line with the word that is split.  Even if I can not keep the brackets `<>`, the numbers will be important to have.

If there is no function in JavaScript, is there one in Python?

Comment: I think in most languages you'd need to work out what the prefix for a line is, and reassemble the strings - adding "<1.0>" and similar to the start of the words from the first line, and so on

Comment: What have you tried so far Jeffrey? We appreciate a bit of effort before coming into the site :) thx

Comment: Seconding @Lucio -- this task is too specialized, so there's probably no magic built-in function to handle it.  You'll need to write some of your own code.  But StackOverflow isn't a free code writing service-- you'll need to put in some of your own efforts first, and come to the community with specific problems you are encountering.

Comment: 1. Iterate over all lines. 2. For each line, use a RegEx to break the line into 2 parts (a. Containing the prefix e.g. <1.0> b. Containing the actual sentence) save both these parts. 3. Now use the split function to split all the words of 2.b. and output it (prefixed with 2.a)...It you can post the code you tried I can try to fix it ;)

Comment: @Lucio Thanks, I was more so looking for a function that maybe I was missing besides str.split(" "), not looking for full blown code.  I based my question on the format of many questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you started.  Go ahead and try and it.  I used a series of split calls to get the information needed.

```
text = """<1.0>The man went up the hill.
<1.1>The woman sat on the bench."""

for line in text.split("\n"):
    parts = line.split(">")
    number = parts[0] + ">"
    for word in parts[1].split(" "):
        print number + word
```